# Magento 2 Nginx and ubuntu Post installation Permission and Ownership issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, installation, nginx, permissions

I have installed Magento2 on AWS EC2 instance.  I am using Nginx, Php-fpm and Ubuntu 18.04 for my magento2 installation.

Magento 2 is installed successfully but whenever I run command php bin/magento cache:flush or php bin/magento setup:upgrade or php bin/magento indexer:reindex

after successful execution site go down.  i need to apply permission **sudo chmod -R 777 ***   then it start working.

I already checked magento's preinstallation and permission & ownership guidline.but seems after running the setup:upgrade or cache:flush site doesn't work until we apply 777 permission.

I have already checked and applied following solutions:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

I also tried following:
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;                        // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;                        // 755 permission for directory

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;                // 777 permission for var folder

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} ;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R : .

chmod u+x bin/magento

Myuser in ubuntu is:  ubuntu

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: `ubuntu` sounds like a sudo user, it should not be related to your web stack at all. NGINX should be running as one user, e.g. `www-data`, while PHP-FPM should run as another user, e.g. `magento`. The `magento` user should be a member of `www-data` group.

Comment: You are right. In this situation what should i do?  How can I have proper permissions?

Comment: Just following my comment, you must first have a proper website user created first. Name it `magento` or whatever you find suitable. It should be a *separate* user that isn't bound to `sudo` privileges, and it should not be same as webserver user. You can follow through [this detailed guide](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-and-php-fpm-what-my-permissions-should-be).

Comment: I really appreciate your help @DanilaVershinin